# "I added 10 litres of petrol to my car's tank at a petrol station"

Tags: sentence-construction

What is idiomatic saying to express that I added 10 litres of petrol to my car's tank at a petrol station?

I filled my car 10 litres of petrol or I filled up my car with 10 litres of petrol? How do you say?

Comment: Note that “filled” and especially “filled up” imply to full capacity, so a quantity is optional.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, idiomatically you would be most likely to refer to the quantity as a price rather than a liquid volume.
Most people in the UK, even though fuel is sold by the litre have really little idea as to how much that actually is. They still think in gallons. Even consumption figures in car adverts are given in miles per gallon. They 'best guess' by considering a gallon to be about 5 litres. Many people judge how much they can get in the tank by how much it costs from nearly empty… & complain about it when the price goes up.*

The most common colloquial way of describing it would be

> I just put a tenner in the car [at the garage. (if there could be any confusion)]

No-one would think you had placed a ten pound note in it.

Again, colloquially, no-one calls it a filling station, just a garage [except, oddly, on the motorway, where you'd call it 'the services', encompassing the entire facility from food courts to filling station]. If you need to be more specific, that's OK, but it's usually just done by context.

You could use quantity, as in

> I just put ten litres in.

You don't need to include *where* you put it [i.e. the petrol tank]. You'd only need further explanation if you had a fuel can in the boot for emergencies that you'd just re-supplied.

As already mentioned, to "fill" would imply you'd put as much fuel in as it would take. Using 'just put xx in' implies you didn't fill it up you merely added some smaller quantity. Using 'put' rather than anything more detailed is really because it needs no further detail.

A common exchange would be along the lines of
"How big's your fuel tank?"
"It takes about ninety quid from empty."
No mention of actual quantity - few people are aware of the true capacity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're interested in British English since you wrote "litres" and "petrol." But just in case, in American English, we might say "I put 10 liters [of gas] in my car." (However, gas in the U.S. is actually measured in gallons.) I think they might say it differently in the U.K.

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenS commented, 'filled' and 'filled up' imply topping up to full capacity.

Google defines it as

> fill
> /fɪl/

> 1. 
>
> cause (a space or container) to become full or almost full.
> "I filled up the bottle with water"

To express having added petrol, without filling the tank, your original suggestion is fine.

> "I added 10 litres of petrol to my car's tank at a petrol station."